# How to correctly circular reference components in Vue 3 with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vite

I have two Vue components. For simplicity of this question I called them **component A** and **component B**.

**Component A**

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ recursive.text }} component A</div>
    <component-b v-if="recursive.value" :recursive="recursive.value" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent } from 'vue';
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'ComponentA',
        components: {
            ComponentB: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./B.vue')),
        },
    });
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    interface RecursiveProp {
        text: string;
        value?: RecursiveProp;
    }

    const props = defineProps<{ recursive: RecursiveProp }>();
</script>
```

**Component B**

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ recursive.text }} component B</div>
    <component-a v-if="recursive.value" :recursive="recursive.value" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent } from 'vue';

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'ComponentB',
        components: {
            ComponentA: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./A.vue')),
        },
    });
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    interface RecursiveProp {
        text: string;
        value?: RecursiveProp;
    }

    const props = defineProps<{ recursive: RecursiveProp }>();
</script>
```

For example, when I import **Component A** into another component and pass it the correct props, the code works with no errors showing in the browser. **Component A** and **Component B** recursively render the specified amount of times based on the given prop. But for some reason Visual Studio Code complains when the components reference to each other in this way. I attached a picture of the error below. This error is present in both **component A** and **component B**.

[image]

In the Vue documentation, this problem is referenced inside the *Handling Edge Cases* section. The only problem is that it is Vue 2 documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components

In Vue 3 you can use *defineAsyncComponent*. This makes my code work, but makes the error appear in Visual Studio code: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#async-components=

I am aware I can globally register one of the components. But that is something I want to avoid.

Is there a way to correctly circular reference components in Vue 3 with Typescript?

Comment: I just wanted to say that if the code is working, it may just be a bug in the VS IDE. I've had this happen before; VS didn't properly highlight code in one of my applications with inline PHP and I just had to comment out the broken portions if I wanted it to work properly when writing code.

Comment: @user1274820 But that would require commenting out the whole script section of the component. The component you are seeing is an example. The logic of the component would be written in the script section you suggest to comment out, which is not workable.

Comment: @Errol59 I'm quite sure the comment suggested that you need to comment it just to edit the file, it may be not workable at this point. It's already done correctly. It's quite common that different tools treat TS and Vue imports differently, including IDE. Switch to another IDE if you have to. Try to avoid `script setup` because it can be processed differently.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this issue only affects `<script lang="ts">` and is unrelated to the IDE or the `<script setup lang="ts">`.

A workaround is to register the recursive async components in `<script setup lang="ts">` instead of `<script lang="ts">`:

```html
<!-- A.vue -->
<template>
    <div>{{ recursive.text }} component A</div>
    <component-b v-if="recursive.value" :recursive="recursive.value" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
           
const ComponentB = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./B.vue')) 

interface RecursiveProp {
    text: string;
    value?: RecursiveProp;
}

const props = defineProps<{ recursive: RecursiveProp }>();
</script>
```

```html
<!-- B.vue -->
<template>
    <div>{{ rec.text }} component B</div>
    <component-a v-if="rec.value" :recursive="rec.value" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent, computed } from 'vue'
         
const ComponentA = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./A.vue'))

interface RecursiveProp {
    text: string;
    value?: RecursiveProp;
}

const props = defineProps<{ recursive: RecursiveProp }>();

// compute stop-condition for the recursion
const rec = computed(() => ({
    ...props.recursive,
    value: undefined
} as RecursiveProp))
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-register-recursive-async-comp-in-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FA.vue)